# Google Nexus S won't turn on

Tags: samsung-nexus-s

My Samsung Nexus S is over a year old now. This morning I was doing a restart (just power down and back on) and it would not finish booting up. The word "Google" on the initial screen comes up, blinks and gets brighter and then just stays there.
I did the reboot sequence (hold power button and up volume) and got it to reboot but then needed to shut it down again and know it will not turn on.
Any help would be appreciated. I am running ICS 4.0.

Comment: Have you tried taking out the battery and holding the buttons to enter "download mode"? If you can there is a way to restore the OS.